# How to evaluate a formula based on different values of one colume in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to evaluate a formula such like
`result = 2*apple - melon - orange` and group by testid.

my df is like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'testid':(1,2,1,2,1,2),'Name':('apple','apple','melon','melon','orange','orange'), 'A': (1,2,10,20,5,5), 'B': (1,5,4,2,3,1)})
```

| testid | Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | apple | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | melon | 10 | 4 |
| 2 | melon | 20 | 2 |
| 1 | orange | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | orange | 5 | 1 |

and I want my result as for each testid's column A and B, do `apple * 2 -  melon - orange`. and then save into new column result_A and result_B, group by testid

| testid | result_A | result_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -13 | -5 |
| 2 | -21 | 7 |

which function can get this result?

I tried to use df.eval() like

```
eq = 'df[df.Name==\'apple\',[\'A\',\'B\']] *2 - df[df.Name==\'melon\',[\'A\',\'B\']] - df[df.Name==\'orange\',[\'A\',\'B\']]'
df.eval(eq)
```

but it tells me

```
UndefinedVariableError: name 'df' is not defined
```

i realized i should use pd.eval(engine='python') instead of df.eval()
and now the problem is that different subset of df return different index which result them cannot add or minus

```
df[df.Name=='apple'][['A','B']]*2
```

this gives me

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 10 |

however

```
df[df.Name=='melon'][['A','B']]
```

this gives me

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 10 | 4 |
| 3 | 20 | 2 |

so they can't add or minus together because index not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (the outside brackets are part of the code, copy them too when you copy this code).

```py
(
    df
    .pivot('testid', 'Name', ['A', 'B'])# reshape df into a wide multiindex df
    .stack(0)                           # remove multiindex
    .eval('apple*2-melon-orange')       # apply formula (creates a Series)
    .unstack()                          # convert to df
    .add_prefix('result_')              # add prefix to column names
    .reset_index()
)
```

[image]

> eval cannot take formula such as `max(apple,0)`, is there another way to evaluate formula with max or if else?

`max(apple, 0)` can be done using `clip()` before `eval()`. Use `assign()` to modify values corresponding to `apple`. Note that `x` inside `assign()` refers to the dataframe that `assign()` is called on.

```py
(
    df
    .pivot('testid', 'Name', ['A', 'B'])
    .stack(0)
    .assign(apple=lambda x: x['apple'].clip(0)) # replace all negative apples to 0s
    .eval('apple*2-melon-orange')
    .unstack()
    .add_prefix('result_')
    .reset_index()
)
```

> I need to evaluate `( melon if ( apple >1 ) else orange ) * 2 - melon - orange`

This can be handled using `where()` inside `assign()` (yet again) to choose values either from `orange` or `melon`.

```py
(
    df
    .pivot('testid', 'Name', ['A', 'B'])
    .stack(0)
    # conditionally choose between melon and orange depending on the value of apple
    .assign(apple=lambda x: x['melon'].where(x['apple']>1, x['orange'])) 
    .eval('apple*2-melon-orange')
    .unstack()
    .add_prefix('result_')
    .reset_index()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method first (assuming there is only one apple, melon, orange for each test id)

```
def compute(g):
  a = g.loc[g['Name']=='apple'].iloc[0]
  m = g.loc[g['Name']=='melon'].iloc[0]
  o = g.loc[g['Name']=='orange'].iloc[0]
  
  return pd.DataFrame({'A':[a['A']*2 - m['A'] - o['A']],
                       'B':[a['B']*2 - m['B'] - o['B']]}, index=pd.Index([0]))
```

Then apply on the group like:

```
   df = df.groupby('testid').apply(compute).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

print(df):

```
   testid   A  B
0       1 -13 -5
1       2 -21  7
```